# Bad repeatability of GC-FID meassurements

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography

I am new to GC-FID and I am struggling with calibration curve. And I am strugling with the repeatability of measurements. One vial measured 5× in a row provides results which differs even 2 orders of magnitude. Do you see any mistakes in my procedure below?

I need to be able to quantify about 12 substances, mostly glycoles. I use methanol as solvent. I determined their retention times and prepared a calibration solution of these substances. All of them were clearly recognisable from each other in the chromatogram.

Since I need to quantify the substances, I prepared 10 solutions of the calibration substances. I need my results in % (*m*/*m*), therefore my calibration series was 10 g of solution + 10 g of methanol, 9 g of solution + 11 g of methanol, 8 g of solution + 12 g of methanol, … , 1 g of solution + 19 g of methanol. I mixed every one of them and fill the vials to the brim. I used only unused septa, put the vials in the refridgerator sealed with parafilm until they are measured.

Every sample was measured 5× in a row and the consequent measurements differed even 2 orders of magnitude. There was no trend in the signal intensity. I am not used to such a behaviour in spectroscopy measurements.

Do you see any mistakes in my procedure? Is there an error in method parametres settings?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: It looks to me like some random technical deviations, possible in sampling ( volume? bubbles in needle ?) or random leaks of gas flow, perhaps due mechanical shocks or vibrations. Try to obtain extensive stats of these errors.

Comment: Thank you @Poutink. I suspect device error, but since I am complete beginner to (practical) chromatography I was not entirely sure.

Comment: Try to make some stat analysis, if values seems to have some statistical distribution, or if there are many outliers. // BTW, I am not going to do any pouting, :-)  Poutnik is a Slavic word ( a pilgrim or a wanderer ).

Comment: OK, I will try to measure one of the solutions 50× that should be enough. Sorry for typing error. I know the word Poutnik. I am also Czech. :-)

Comment: «Bad repeatability» may refer to many different outcomes.  Regardless of the manufacturer of your GC, however, nothing prevents you to look up the troubleshoot guides, e.g., by [gcms.cz](https://gcms.cz/labrulez-bucket-strapi-h3hsga3/application::paper.paper/Seminar-GC-Troubleshooting.pdf), papers and videos e.g. by [Agilent](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiI8ujNj_vvAhVNgv0HHeKiBF4QFjACegQIFBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.agilent.com%2Fcs%2Flibrary%2Feseminars%2Fpublic%2FGC_Troubleshooting_09072017.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2N7S6LD9D6PmklMHNyPPTX)

Comment: A deep dive may be books specialized on all sort of pitfalls, e.g. [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9783527611300).

Comment: Thank you both. It seems it was really something with sampling. With the help of the troubleshoot guides, I tried to remove and clean the syringe. Then I obtained the same result five times in a row. It seems I can continue with the calibration process.